# How to check if file is not symlink in python

Tags: python, filesystems

current running code is:

```
for y in checkdirlist:
    if (y in no_exec or y.endswith(".ebuild")) and \
        stat.S_IMODE(os.stat(os.path.join(checkdir, y)).st_mode) & 0o111:
```

and stat fails with symlink files.

I want to add some check if y is symlink or not.

`lstat` solves the problem with system error but it's not over in general

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/repoman", line 1385, in <module>
    myaux = dict(zip(allvars, portdb.aux_get(cpv, allvars)))
  File "/usr/lib/portage/pym/portage/dbapi/porttree.py", line 435, in aux_get
    myebuild, mylocation = self.findname2(mycpv, mytree)
  File "/usr/lib/portage/pym/portage/dbapi/porttree.py", line 308, in findname2
    raise InvalidPackageName(mycpv)
portage.exception.InvalidPackageName: dev-haskell/.#hakyll-9999
```

I want to filter those files so I need to know which ones are symlinks.

Comment: Have you considered using `os.lstat` instead of `os.stat`?

Comment: No, I'm very new with python. And just want to patch existing project. What is core difference between stat and lstat?

Comment: `stat` follows symbolic links and returns the stat of the file pointed to via links (or fails if any of them refer to a non-existent path), while `lstat` returns the stat of the link and does not follow links.

Comment: Is there some reason than `os.path.islink(y)` won't work?  [Non-rhetorical, by the way -- there are often corner cases I don't think of.]

Comment: by the way, you don't need the backslash there, inside parentheses you can break lines freely

Comment: so question is solved now, must I delete it? @DSM islink works just fine

Comment: @pythonm my IDE highlights red without blackslashes (kdevelop)

Comment: @nCdy: I'll make my comment an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs, you probably want [os.path.islink](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink):

> os.path.islink(path)
>
> ```
> Return True if path refers to a directory entry that is a symbolic link. 
> Always False if symbolic links are not supported.
> ```